# Visual Basic: How to get entire section before/after a certain character?

Tags: arrays, string, vb6, split

I have a string. For example *stringone/string2*

How do I get the section before the "/" and also after the "/"

```
Dim Word As String = "stringone/string2"
Dim wordArr As String() = Word.Split("/")
Dim stringBefore As String = wordArr(???)
Dim stringBefore As String = wordArr(???)
```

What is the next step

Answer (score 3):

Split() returns an Array.  The first element is at Index 0 (zero), the second element is at Index 1 (one), etc...

You should check to make sure the returned array is your expected size (at least), otherwise you'll get an error attempting to access an index slot that doesn't exist.

```
    Dim Word As String = "stringone/string2"
    Dim wordArr As String() = Word.Split("/")
    If wordArr.Length = 2 Then
        Dim stringBefore As String = wordArr(0)
        Dim stringAfter As String = wordArr(1)

        Debug.Print("stringBefore = " & stringBefore)
        Debug.Print("stringAfter = " & stringAfter)
    End If
```

*By the way, the code you posted is not VB6, it's VB.Net.

Comment: Would there be a `wordArr(3)` if it was `"stringone/string2/str3"`?

Comment: No sir, there would only be three elements at indexes 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: That's what I meant. `wordArr(2)` Thanks. It's getting pretty late here. I should sleep.